# How to add number scale inside android seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I'm trying with the custom seekbar inside have number scale, But is not working. This seekbar must support all screen resolutions. how can i make like this. Please give your valuable idea.

My custom_seekbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/unselect"/>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/select">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/select">
</item>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/default_screen_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="10"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Unselesct.png

[image]

select.png

[image]

myresult screen like this

[image]

I'm expecting like this

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do You mean by 'not working'? What is drawable/unselect etc. images? Are these images not displayed properly?

Comment: @sandrstar Yes. Select and unselect images not displaying properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's number to solutions to the problem:

- Use [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image for backgorund (which is basically *should* be used as background for seekbar). Like the following:

[image] (name should be `unselect_patch.9.png`) and slightly modify `custom_seekbar.xml` to look like the following:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unselect_patch"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:src="@drawable/select"
                android:tileMode="disabled" />
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:src="@drawable/select"
                android:tileMode="disabled" />
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

- Just provide exact size of the image in layout (e.g. `layout_width="@dimen/select_image_width"`);

To support all resolutions - provide images for different resolutions, as described in [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). The same images will not work fine for all resolutions and here's better just follow best practices described in detail at the link above.

Comment: @sandrstar can u help me if i want numbers from 1 to 142  then may i need to put image that must contain numbers from 1 to 142 or is there any method that can draw scale like lines and numbers using onDraw()  that should produce final image like above

Comment: @ErumHannan no, there's no such method, if You need custom draw, then seek bar should be extended and onDraw() hooked.

Comment: @sandrstar can u help me regarding this any idea ..... how will i draw may i need to take any loop for displaying of scale like lines till 4 and then 5th line should be large enough and again 4 lines

Comment: can u pls come in chat

Comment: @ErumHannan if You need help with some particular drawing, I would suggest to research custom views first and then (if any issues) share your code and raise new question. Unfortunately, now I can provide only general idea, because there might be some issues with exact implementation.

Comment: whats the general idea ?

Comment: @ErumHannan 1) implement custom view which extends SeekBar, override onDraw() and provide own drawing of background. 2) also, you can try to create that background programatically and set as SeekBar background. I think both ideas might work fine, but it's difficult to say which one will be more applicable in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58843/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-sandrstar).