# Customising Seekbar in Android is not working fine

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

i am customising seekbar in android 
here bolow is my code

process.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_bg_new"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip
        android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_bg_fill_new"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
</item>
```

AND MY SEEKBAR IN LAYOUT XML

```
<SeekBar
           android:id="@+id/seekbar_education_plan_investment_duration"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="0dp"
           android:progressDrawable="@drawable/process"
           android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

OUTPUT :-
[image]

and when progress=50
[image]

it working fine between progress=3 to progress=98
it is not looking well from left and right side 
paddingLeft/Right is not working
i have try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227559/how-to-create-custom-layout-for-seekbar-in-android) , [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929416/how-to-add-number-scale-inside-android-seekbar) , [and THIS](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/) too 
please help me 
thanx in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the android:paddingLeft, android:paddingRight and android:thumbOffset properties of your SeekBar to achieve desired results.

Padding right and left should be half of thumbs width.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` not work. use `android:paddingStart`,`android:paddingEnd` instead

```
<SeekBar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_49sdp"
android:background="@drawable/statelist_bg_redeem_slider"
android:max="100"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_46sdp"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/_46sdp"
android:progressDrawable="@null"
/>
```