# seekbar with fixed intervals,one thumb and thumb will have only 5 steps

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

i want to create seek bar as shown in image.
[image]

I have check almost all libraries but those are not suitable to my requirement.In seek bar i have intervals user can select only these intervals only.For example user drag thumb to middle of 0 to 25 thumb need to place in 25 interval.If anyone have suggestions it will help me.My ultimate motive is user can select 0,25,50,75,100 only.
If any one knows please,post answer it will help me a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929416/how-to-add-number-scale-inside-android-seekbar

Comment: @Ankita i need intervals where user can select and i need to get that selected value by using background image it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply logic like if progress is greater than 0 && progress is less than 25 make progress equals to 25.

Comment: Hi @Daya Shankar,but i want intervals also in seek bar,without them user don't know what he selected.Is any idea u have about it.